ImageDataGenerator sending array of image, instead of file path in preprocessing function
I am trying to implement a Deep learning project in python, that

takes Image as input
detects one human
tells the color of cloths, that human wearing.

I have a folder which have all training images and a dataframe of two attributes:

'img_name': contains image name, corresponding to name of image in folder.
'color': contains color of human's cloth.

For dataset I am using photo of 1 human only.
For pre-processing, I decided to use yolov3, to detect any random human in image and using open-cv crop the rest of image, which worked fine (When tested manually).
However, when i tried to store it using ImageDataGenerator of tensorflow, for some reason instead of path, it sending some Image array in file path.
My preprocessing cell
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Load YOLO model
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights', 'yolov3.cfg')
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

# Read and process image
image = cv2.imread('visual-taxonomy/train_images/000234.jpg')
height, width, channels = image.shape
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
outs = net.forward(output_layers)

# Process output and break after detecting one human
human_detected = False  # Flag to indicate detection
detections = []

def crop_human_from_image(image):
    
    # Process output and break after detecting one human
    human_detected = False  # Flag to indicate detection
    detections = []
    
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            if len(detection) > 5:  # Ensure valid detection format
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                if confidence > 0.5 and class_id == 0:  # 0 is the class for 'person'
                    center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                    center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                    w = int(detection[2] * width)
                    h = int(detection[3] * height)
                    x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                    y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                    detections.append((x, y, w, h))
                    human_detected = True
        if human_detected:
            break

    # Randomly select one human from detected humans if any exist
    if detections:
        x, y, w, h = random.choice(detections)
        print(x,y,w,h)
        # cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
        image = image[y:y+h+1, x:x+w+1]
        
    return image  # Return the original image if no human is detected

def preprocess_image(file_path):
    # Ensure that file_path is a string
    if isinstance(file_path, str):
        # Load the image
        try:
            image = cv2.imread(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(f"--------------------filepath||||{file_path}|||--------------")
            image = np.zeros((decided_size, decided_size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        
        # Crop the image to only include the detected human
        cropped_image = crop_human_from_image(image)
        
        # Resize and normalize
        cropped_image = cv2.resize(cropped_image, (decided_size, decided_size))
        cropped_image = cropped_image / 255.0
        return cropped_image
    else:
        print(f"Expected file_path to be str, but got {type(file_path)}")
        return np.zeros((decided_size, decided_size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)



My Code to store in ImageDataGenerator
# Set parameters
image_size = (decided_size, decided_size)  # Size for MobileNet
batch_size = 32


# Create ImageDataGenerator with the custom preprocessing function
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_image,
    validation_split=0.2
)

# Create generators
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    directory=image_folder,
    x_col='img_name',
    y_col='attr_1',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training'
)

for _ in range(1):  # Check the first 5 batches
    x_batch, y_batch = next(train_generator)
    print(f"x_batch shape: {x_batch.shape}, y_batch shape: {y_batch.shape}")

Error:
Expected file_path to be str, but got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Expected file_path to be str, but got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Expected file_path to be str, but got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Expected file_path to be str, but got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.... 32 times

Also, in my case I can't use image_dataset_from_directory.
Is my implementation is wrong, and if yes, how to fix it?
